# JavaScript array getting encoded when posting jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm trying to post part of my Knockout viewmodel to our server using jQuery.Ajax.
When I build the data object it looks fine in the console, but when it gets sent via the jQuery Ajax Post the array within gets encoded.  The results on the other end are readable by the server, so it works, but it disturbs me greatly (the payload is bigger for one thing).
Here's the code:

```
var items = $.map(self.Items(), function (item) {
    return item.Key() ? {
        Key: item.Key(),
        PromoCode: item.PromoCode,
        Qty: parseInt(item.Qty(), 10)
    } : undefined;
}),
data = {
    "InEditMode": true,
    "Items": items
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/order/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (order) {
    <snip>
```

The result as seen by FireBug is this.
Here's the decoded JSON Object

```
InEditMode  true
Items[0][Key]   2730M0ARAX1111AAAAX0
Items[0][PromoCode] 
Items[0][Qty]   3
Items[1][Key]   2730M0ARCX1111AAAAX0
Items[1][PromoCode] 
Items[1][Qty]   5
```

Here's the Raw view
    InEditMode=true&
    Items%5B0%5D%5BKey%5D=2730M0ARAX1111AAAAX0&
    Items%5B0%5D%5BPromoCode%5D=&
    Items%5B0%5D%5BQty%5D=3&
    Items%5B1%5D%5BKey%5D=2730M0ARCX1111AAAAX0&
    Items%5B1%5D%5BPromoCode%5D=&
    Items%5B1%5D%5BQty%5D=5

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Firstly, the dataType parameter is the type of data you're expecting back from the server -- if you missed that part.  Secondly, you aren't specifying 'application/json' as your content type, so it is using the default of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', which is why you are seeing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Like @codenoire said in his comment, you aren't specifying the content type. Add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` to your `$.ajax` call, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/order/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (order) {
    <snip>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to stringify your JSON object before you post it. Use `JSON.stringify(data)` before you post it.

Answer (score 0):

I was so close!  The answer is a combination of rwisch45 and Saeedses
I had already tried adding the contentType before, but that caused it to break and I hadn't pursued it any further then that.
the solution is to add the content type AND JSON.stringify it, as so.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/order/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (order) {
```

Thanks all for your help!